# How can I increment from 1st to 2nd to 3rd when an existing Data is present in VB.net/Mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, phpmyadmin

Seriously need help. Been figuring this one out for days and I can't seem to get it. Tried all the codes I searched but still no luck. 
So here's the problem, for every added existing violation in a student in tablestudentviolation, The numberofviolation will increase from 1st to 2nd to 3rd. How can I do that? I'll post my codes (current in progress codes) and screenshot of the mysql table below for reference

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Mysqlconn = New MySqlConnection
    Mysqlconn.ConnectionString =
        "server=localhost;uid=root;password=;database=cdm"
    Try
        Mysqlconn.Open()
        Dim query As String
        query = "select * from cdm.tablestudentviolations where NameOfViolation = '" & ComboBox1.Text & "' and NumberOfViolation = LAST_INSERT_ID()"
        command = New MySqlCommand(query, Mysqlconn)

        Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader

        If reader.HasRows Then
            command = New MySqlCommand(query, Mysqlconn)
            reader = command.ExecuteReader
        Else

            Dim query1 As String
            Dim reader1 As MySqlDataReader
            Dim command1 As MySqlCommand
            query1 = "insert into cdm.tablestudentviolations (StudentNumber,NameOfViolation,Remarks,NumberOfViolation,EmployeeUsername,EmployeeID) values ('" & Studnum.Text & "','" & ComboBox1.Text & "','" & RichTextBox1.Text & "','" & Label2.Text & "', '" & Form5.Label4.Text & "','2')"
            command1 = New MySqlCommand(query1, Mysqlconn)
            reader1 = command1.ExecuteReader
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    End Try
End Sub
```

[image: My table:]

Comment: You'd have to query the database to get the number of violations currently present for that student, then add 1 to that yourself. A database can generate sequential values but generally not for specific subsets of data like that.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Oh I see. So I should do the 1st 2nd 3rd thingy manually?

Comment: I would suggest just storing the number in the database, so that it can be treated numerically, e.g. sorted and incremented, then perform the conversion/formatting , for example, from 1 to "1st" for display purposes manually. That's fairly easy using a `Select Case` and adding a suffix to the number. You need specific cases for numbers ending in 1, 2 and 3 and everything else gets "th" appended.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thanks! Would try that suggestion!